# Struts2 jqGrid issues in IE6

Tags: jqgrid, struts2, internet-explorer-6, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

Is there any alternative which can make struts2 jqgrid better in IE6. The images are sample images. 
In my application I have developed several grids using plugins All are working fine in all browsers but looking weird in IE6

You can find the differences between them  IN IE6 header columns looks weird and that hide/unhide button also missing .. 
Please help me how to fix this thing My application has to work in IE6 
[image: Struts2 JqGrid in IE7]

[image: Struts2 Jqgrid in IE6]

versoins I am using

```
 Struts2-core 2.3.8 
 Struts2-jquery-grid-3.6.1
 Struts2 jQuery-3.6.1
```

This one is the html code by clicking on view source

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="struts2,jquery, hibernate, plugin,showcase, grid" />
<meta http-equiv="description" content="Showcase for Struts2 jQuery Grid Plugin and Full Hibernate Struts2 Plugins" />

<title>Struts2 jQuery Grid Plugin Showcase - 3.7.0</title>

<link href="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/styles/flexible-grids.css;jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/yaml/core/iehacks.min.css;jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->






        <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/struts/js/base/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/struts/js/base/jquery-ui.min.js?s2j=3.7.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/struts/js/plugins/jquery.form.min.js?s2j=3.7.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js?s2j=3.7.0"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.7.0"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
jQuery.struts2_jquery.version="3.7.0";
jQuery.struts2_jquery.debug = true;
jQuery.struts2_jquery.loadAtOnce = true;
jQuery.scriptPath = "/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/struts/";
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.7.0");

     });
     </script>

        <link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/showcase/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.7.0" type="text/css"/>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var employee_detail_url = '/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/employees-detail.action;jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D';
  </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/js/showcase.js;  jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D"></script>
   </head>
 <body>

    <header class="ui-widget-header">
<div class="ym-wrapper">
    <div class="ym-wbox" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
        <div>
            <h1 class="ui-state-default" style="background: none; border: none; margin: 0;">Showcase for Struts2 jQuery Grid Plugin and Full Hibernate Struts2 Plugins</h1>
            <h4 class="ui-state-default" style="background: none; border:  none;">Struts2 jQuery Plugin - Version 3.7.0 / Full Hibernate Plugin - Version 2.2.1 GA</h4>
        </div>
  </div>
   </header>

    <nav id="nav" class="ui-widget-header">
<div class="ym-wrapper">
    <div class="ym-hlist">
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a id="gridlink" href="javascript:void(0)">Grid (Editable)</a>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
     jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
var options_gridlink = {};
options_gridlink.jqueryaction = "anchor";
options_gridlink.id = "gridlink";
options_gridlink.targets = "main_content";
options_gridlink.href = "/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-  3.7.0/grid.action;jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D";

        jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind(jQuery('#gridlink'),options_gridlink);

       });  
         </script></li>
            <li><a id="gridsubgridlink" href="javascript:void(0)">Grid with  Subgrid</a>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
var options_gridsubgridlink = {};
options_gridsubgridlink.jqueryaction = "anchor";
options_gridsubgridlink.id = "gridsubgridlink";
options_gridsubgridlink.targets = "main_content";
options_gridsubgridlink.href = "/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/grid-  subgrid.action;jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D";

       jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind(jQuery('#gridsubgridlink'),options_gridsubgridlink);

    });  
   </script></li>
            <li><a id="griddndlink" href="javascript:void(0)">Grid with Drag   and Drop</a>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
     jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
var options_griddndlink = {};
options_griddndlink.jqueryaction = "anchor";
options_griddndlink.id = "griddndlink";
options_griddndlink.targets = "main_content";
options_griddndlink.href = "/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.7.0/grid-  dnd.action;jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D";

    jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind(jQuery('#griddndlink'),options_griddndlink);

  });  
    </script></li>
            <li><a href="http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/">Struts2 jQuery Plugin</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-   for-struts2/">Full Hibernate Plugin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
  </nav>


 <div id="main">
<div class="ym-wrapper">
    <div id="main_content"

 class="ym-wbox"


  >
        <img id="indicator" src="images/indicator.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
    </div><script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
var options_main_content = {};
options_main_content.jqueryaction = "container";
options_main_content.id = "main_content";
options_main_content.href = "/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-   3.7.0/grid.action;jsessionid=3934431750DCFB5887508B8F186FD38D";


  jQuery.struts2_jquery.bind(jQuery('#main_content'),options_main_content);

  });  
 </script>

</div>
 </div>

 <footer>
<div class="ym-wrapper">
    <div class="ym-wbox">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            Written by  <a href="http://www.jgeppert.com" title="Java Developer Blog">Johannes Geppert</a> and <a href="http://jyoshiriro.blogspot.com" title="Java Developer Blog">Jos&eacute; Yoshiriro</a><br/>
            Layout based on <a href="http://www.yaml.de/" title="OpenSource CSS Layout">YAML</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Which plugin version do you use? Newest jquery and jqGrid versions does not support IE6 anymore. Try older plugin versions or accept that  IE6 is not supported anymore. :-)

Comment: Why that IE6? IE11 is your possible choice.

Comment: @roman users are using IE6 .. So i have no choice to change them . You mean Struts2 is not for IE6  users ?

Comment: @jogep I have edited my question please check .. Which version will support IE6 please advise .

Comment: not familiar with struts, but those all look like style issues, down to the images missing, if they are .png.  bet you could fix it all by serving up separate style sheet for ie6 using conditional comments. hard to tell entirely without looking at the codes though. put them on jsfiddle or share al ink

Comment: @albert Those are the grids generated by the tags of `struts2 jquery-grid plugin` .. May be they are style issues .For code refer this link http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/

Comment: again, without looking its impossible to say...but, again, offhand thats exactly what it looks like...ie6 only supports one type of .png, and no one ever used that, so it pretty much doesn't. your pix aren't showing up....and i'll bet the rows at the top and bottom with the glossy-ish background are .png too. if so, yo this is really easy. show me markup and styles yo

Comment: I dont know how to explain to you .. Those tables are generated by the tags i have used if you want I can provide you those tags code . Okay i will provide you generated HtML code.

Comment: @albert This link is exactly what i have done http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag . Everything is working fine but IE6 is problem as you said `.png` pics may be exist if they exist how to manipulate them .. :(

Comment: that doesn't look anything like your pix. targeting ie6 is easy using conditional comments. wrap up a separate style sheet targeting ie6 in conditonal comments. wherever you have .png being used as background-image, swap out for .gif. so you need to convert them too.

Comment: <!--[if IE6]><style>.whatever{background-image:("pix.gif");</style><!--[endif]>  the syntax for conditionals may be off cause i'm doing this really fast, but thats the jist of it.

Comment: I have tried that but no luck